# How to call/wrap Scintilla? Doubts

Tags: scintilla

I want wrap Scintilla in Delphi/FreePascal component and Java JNI. My doubts:
After compiling source under Windows, it create two libraries: SciLexer.dll (~960 KB) and Scintilla.dll (~460 KB) which library I must use?
Libraries have only one function: Scintilla_DirectFunction, which is never called in examples.
In examples (dmapp.zip and [How to start a project with Scintilla?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371965/how-to-start-a-project-with-scintilla)) is ::LoadLibrary("SciLexer.DLL"); but never is remembered handle of this library! Only is created some window and sendmessages. How it works?

Answer (score 0):

1. SciLexer.dll contains all the lexers(under scintilla\lexers), while Scintilla.dll does not.
2. Check this out:http://www.scintilla.org/Steps.html